# Retina css isn't working

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display, retina

have a problem with using media query for changing font-weight. 
So, im using `font-weight: 100;` only for Retina. And `font-weight: 300` for PC's.

That's my CSS:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
a {
    font-weight: 100;
}
}
a {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Browser just ignores @media and using the font-weight: 300

Comment: In which browser? Which resolution are you using on the device you're testing it on?

Comment: @connexo, im testing on safari and chrome

Comment: @connexo, and i tested it on macbook retina display

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your mediaqueried CSS after the general definition, as media queries have no higher specificity than un-mediaqueried CSS rules.

Also, you forgot to put the closing bracket of your media query, so both css rules belong to the media query and get applied, the latter one "winning". Fix it:

```
a {
    font-weight: 700;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
    a {
        font-weight: 100;
    }
} /* <- close your media query properly */
```

It works then.

### Edit:

The reason it still seems to be not working for you (which it **does**) may also be that there is no difference in display between those two font-weights. Try to apply 700 and 100, and you'll see it works.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGdpEy

Comment: sorry, for confusing, actually i have this in code, just missed here. still dosn't work

Comment: Still not working :( 
Browser ignores @media and if i put `@media` upper, @media css works, if i put simple `a { ... }` upper - it works.

Comment: I have checked on my MBP Retina Late 2013 @1920x1200 and 2840x1800 in Chrome and Safari (both latest versions). It **does** work flawlessly here.

Comment: Did you re-check? Also, how did you find out that your browser ignores your style definition in the media query? By the looks, or have you checked in Chrome Developer Tools?